# Setting up Back propagation net with 150k training samples

Tags: neural-network, classification, backpropagation, training-data, feed-forward

I am trying to build a backpropagation neural net to classify 150k thousand accounts of loans. Each account has data on age, average income, and date they were issued the loan.  I also have to target which is where or not they paid 1(paid), -1(did not pay). I am wondering what the best way is to set up the architecture of the net so it can correctly train and classify the data I have.

The input right now is an array of 10 values(1 or -1) based off their data that I have. How many hidden layers and neurons in each layer will best handle this data?

Anything to help or steer me in the correct direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: what architectures have you tried? As you only have 10 inputs and one output, you shouldn't layer too much as that might overfit your data. You should experiment yourself through trial and error, as your input is not very large (you don't have to use all 150k samples to figure out a good amount of layers)

Comment: Right now I have the 10 inputs, with a hidden layer of 10 neurons and the one output layer. I use bipolar sigmoid activation function.                                        I have 4 age groups each one gets an input [1,-1,-1,-1] or [-1,1,-1,-1]... ect    and 3 income groups with the same [1,-1,1]. ect and then i combine the arrays for the final input so if someone is in first age group and first income group they have the array [1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1](three more values for date)